# ownProps in list item edit value disappears

Tags: reactjs, redux

My container looks like this:

ItemContainer.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => () =>
  console.log('ownprops.edit is:', ownProps.edit) ||
  selectTaskItem(ownProps);
```

The list component looks like this:

```
<Item
  item={item}
  edit={console.log('passing edit:', edit) || edit}
  key={item.id}
/>
```

It logs the following

```
List.js:22 passing edit: {1: {…}}
List.js:22 passing edit: {1: {…}}
List.js:22 passing edit: {1: {…}}
Item.js:6 ownprops.edit is: {}
Item.js:6 ownprops.edit is: {}
Item.js:6 ownprops.edit is: {}
```

There are 3 items so it logs 3 times in List.js and 3 times in Item but edit disappears between the logs and I have no clue where it went.

Answer (score 0):

In a list item you can have mapStateToProps return a function but ownProps are passed in the function that is returned:

```
const mapStateToProps = () => (state, ownProps) =>
  console.log('ownprops.edit is:', ownProps.edit) ||
  selectTaskItem(ownProps);
```